# How to use DateTime.UtcNow inside javascript function to display javascript clock?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clock

There is a pretty simple javascript clock like below

```
        <script>
        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('clockSpan').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        t = setTimeout(function () { startTime() }, 500);
    }

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
</script>
```

But it uses browser time settings. Instead i want to use server time.

How can i do something like this ?

```
      var today = new Date(<%=DateTime.UtcNow%>);
```

It gives error like this

[image]

asp.net 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing delimiters around the string, but that depends on the date format produces by the server being understood by the browser. Instead, calculate the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 and use the `Date` constructor that takes that as a value:

```
var today = new Date(<%=(int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds%>);
```

However, you have to rewrite the code to use both the server date and the browser date. You can only get the time of the page loading using that code. Each time you run the function it will display the same time, so you have to get the server time into a variable once, and the browser time as soon as the page has loaded in the browser, and get the difference. From that you can calculate the server time from the browser time later on.

Comment: What will happen if he has his IIS in Italy where the decimal separator is a `,`? Will the `TotalMilliseconds` (that is a `double`) be passed correctly? (I'm quite sure not, but it's always difficult to search the documentation of `<%= %>`... It probably uses `ToString()`, right?)

Comment: @xanatos: That's why the value is cast to an `int`.

Comment: I hadn't noticed... At least now the questioner will know the reason for the cast. Now your code is perfect at least until `2038-01-19` :-) (I would have casted to `long`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using JavaScript it is impossible to get data from the server using any pre-built methods, instead if you are looking for the time from a specific server you will need to make some form of AJAX (maybe asp.net AJAX juding on the tags) call to a PHP (or other) script to return the time for you which you can use to construct your Date object.